# Creating dynamic graphql query using apollo/client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, hasura

I am trying to create a graphql query where the query data type and filter parameters will be passed dynamically based on user input.

I have written the below query which filters using only one field `shipdate`.

```
const GET_SHIPDATA_WITH_FILTER = gql`
  query GetShipData($shipdateStart: timestamptz, $shipdateEnd: timestamptz, $limit: Int) {
    shipdata(where: {shipdate: { _gte: $shipdateStart, _lte: $shipdateEnd}},limit: $limit) {
      status
      import_time
      shipdate
    }
  }
`;

const variables = {
  shipdateStart: "some date",
  shipdateEnd: "some date",
  limit: 50,
};
```

If no filter is passed I'm using this one

```
const GET_SHIPDATA = gql`
  query GetShipData($limit: Int) {
    shipdata(limit: $limit) {
      status
      import_time
      shipdate
    }
  }
`;
const variables = {
  limit: 50,
};
```

You can see I have written two queries to handle two types of filters which won't work if I want to add more filters.

Now I am trying to write a single dynamic query where if the user wants to add more filters like `status: {_eq: $status}` or `import_time: { _gt: $importTimeStart, _lt: $importTimeEnd}` then I will pass the variables and the query will dynamically handle the filters. Something like

```
const GET_SHIPDATA = gql`
  query GetShipData($allfilters: AllFilterTypes) {
    shipdata(filter: $allfilters) {
      status
      import_time
      shipdate
    }
  }
`;
const variables = {
  //pass allFilters based on user input,
};
```

Btw I'm using react and hasura if it helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hasura already exposes types in your GraphQL schema that refer to "filter conditions". In Hasura, they're called Bool_Exp (short for boolean expression) and they map directly to the `where` clause.

If you just update your query to receive a `shipdata_bool_exp` you'll be able to build up a dynamic filter expression in your application code and it will work as expected.

```
const GET_SHIPDATA_WITH_FILTER = gql`
  query GetShipData($filter: shipdata_bool_exp!) {
    shipdata(where: $filter,limit: $limit) {
      status
      import_time
      shipdate
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to receive the `shipdata_bool_exp` and how to pass the filter with `_gt` or `_lt` from the `variables`?